# std::array constructor behaves different between compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, copy-constructor

I have the following code where `b` is list-initialized with another array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> a{1,2,3,4};
    std::array<int, 4> b{a};
    std::cout<<b[3]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering why this code compiles under one compiler used by [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q3v1OtzNHXvvV5PP).

But it fails by another compiler used by [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/9pzba).

Comment: As the dupe points out this has since been fixed and cpp.sh is using a fairly out of date compiler.

Comment: @NathanOliver, your point about `cpp.sh` is not reflected in the linked answer. So I disagree with marking this question as duplicate.

Comment: cpp.sh might not be but the version of gcc it uses is.  cpp.sh uses 4.9.2, and the dupe points out it is fixed in 5.0.

Comment: If you use version 4.9.2 in wandbox you'd also get a compiler error.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Thank you Nathan. Still not convinced for marking as duplication. You could post it as an answer.